# Create a new enumeration constant from an existing one

Tags: c, enums

I have the following enumeration:

```
typedef enum Items
{
    ITEM_1
  , ITEM_2
  , ITEM_3
} Items_t
```

I want to create a new enumeration using the first one. The result will be like this:

```
typedef enum Items_New
{
    ITEM_1
  , ITEM_2
  , ITEM_2_1
  , ITEM_2_2
  , ITEM_3
} Items_New_t;
```

Is there a way to create the second enum using the first?

Comment: What does it mean 'using the first one'??

Comment: It means the first enumeration Items_t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `enum`s in C do not provide anything like "namespace", your `Items_New` would not compile, because it redeclares `ITEM_1`, `ITEM_2`, and `ITEM_3`.

One way to make an `enum` that "picks up where the other `enum` left off" would be as follows:

```
typedef enum Items_New
{
    ITEM_2_1 = ITEM_3+1
,   ITEM_2_2
}   Items_New_t;
```

The numeric values associated with `ITEM_2_1` and `ITEM_2_2` would be *after* the value of `ITEM_3`. If you want to be able to "insert items in the middle", you need to prepare your first `enum` for that by leaving some space, for example:

```
typedef enum Items
{
    ITEM_1 = 1000
,   ITEM_2 = 2000
,   ITEM_3 = 3000
} Items_t;

typedef enum Items_New
{
    ITEM_2_1 = ITEM_2 + 100
,   ITEM_2_2 = ITEM_2 + 200
}   Items_New_t;
```

> I can not use a loop from `ITEM_1` to `ITEM_3` taking into account `ITEM_2_1` and `ITEM_2_2`

It is a very bad idea to make loops from `ITEM_1` to `ITEM_3`, because such loops make assumptions about numeric values of `enum`s - the very thing the `enum`s are designed to hide. If you would like to iterate over `enum` values in a specific order, make an array:

```
Items_New_t items_in_order[] = {ITEM_1, ITEM_2, ITEM_2_1, ITEM_2_2, ITEM_3};
...
for (int i = 0 ; i != sizeof(items_in_order)/sizeof(items_in_order[0]) ; i++) {
    Items_New_t item = items_in_order[i];
    ...
}
```

Now your iteration order is guaranteed independently of the numeric values of constants behind your `enum`.

Comment: If i wrote ITEM_2_1 = ITEM_3+1, i can not use a loop from ITEM_1 to ITEM_3 taking into account ITEM_2_1 and ITEM_2_2

Comment: @StackOver You wouldn't be able to do it anyway without making an assumption about numeric values of `ITEM_XXX`, which goes against the purpose of having an `enum` in the first place. `enum`s are there to hide numeric values; exposing them back is extremely error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't "concatenate" enumerations.

You can refer to the values of the first, but that will be very repetitive:

```
enum OldEnum {
  OLD_ITEM_1 = 100,
  OLD_ITEM_2 = 101,
};

enum NewEnum {
  NEW_ITEM_1 = OLD_ITEM_1,
  NEW_ITEM_2 = OLD_ITEM_2,
  NEW_ITEM_3  /* This will be 102. */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe enums are not the proper way to solve your problem**.

What about using plain old macros? You don't get the "autoincrement" feature, but maybe you don't even need it. What about stating the actual problem you have, instead of the attempt at solving it with enum inheritance?